# How to use reflection to intercept an expression prior to evaluation?

Tags: r, reflection

I was hoping to use R's reflection capabilities to intercept the current expression under evaluation before it is evaluated.

For instance, to create some syntax sugar, given the following:

```
> Server <- setRefClass("Server",
>   methods = list(
>       handler = function(expr) submitExpressionToRemoteServer(expr)
>   )
> )
> server <- Server()
> server$foo$bar$baz    #... should be map to...    server$handler("foo$bar$baz")
```

I want the expression `server$foo$bar$baz` to be intercepted by the `server$handler`method and get mapped to `server$handler("foo$bar$baz")`.

Note that I want this call to succeed even though `server$foo` is not defined: I am interested only in the *expression itself* (so I can do stuff with the expression), not that it evaluates to a valid local object.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to redefine the `$` behavior with Reference Classes (R5) objects in R. However, this is something that you can do with S4 classes. The main problem is that an expression like

```
server$foo$bar$baz
```

would get translated to a series of calls like

```
$($($(server,"foo"),"bar"),"baz")
```

but unlike normal function nesting, each inner call appears to be fully evaluated before going to the next level of nesting. This it's not really possible just to split up everything after the first `$` because that's not how it's parsed. However you can have the `$` function return another object and append all the values sent to the object. Here's a sample S4 class

```
setClass("Server", slots=list(el="character"))
setMethod("$", signature(x="Server"), 
   function(x,name) {
    xx <- append(slot(x,"el"),name)
    new("Server", el=xx)
   }
)

server <- new("Server")    
server$foo$bar$baz

# An object of class "Server"
# Slot "el":
# [1] "foo"   "bar" "baz"
```

the only problem is there's no way i've found to know when you're at the end of  a list if you wanted to do anything with those parameters.

Comment: That's one scary overload operation!  :-)